# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Why?

Tags: sql-server

What am i missing?

```
create table Diver(
diver_number int  primary key check(diver_number>0) not null,
first_name char(30) not null,
last_name char(30) not null,
fullname AS first_name+' '+last_name,
bithdate date not null,
email nchar(100) not null,
diver_password  char(8) not null check(Len(diver_password) = 8 
   AND diver_password not like('%[^a-z0-9]%')),
diver_signature nchar(200) not null,
signature_date date not null,
old_diving_diaries nchar(200))


insert into Diver VALUES('1111','Dana','shwartz','1966/04/11','danas@gmail.com','dana1234','http://www.google.co.il','')
```

I'm getting this error:
    Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
     Why?

Comment: Because your table has 10 columns and your query 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, the error pretty much speaks for itself. You're trying to insert 8 values into a table with 10 columns.

Consider listing the column names you wish to insert into explicitly

```
insert into Diver (column names here)
VALUES('1111','Dana','shwartz','1966/04/11','danas@gmail.com','dana1234','http://www.google.co.il','')
```

Comment: Ofcours. Didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You miss old_diving_diaries.
You need to chage the values to

```
VALUES('1111','Dana','shwartz','1966/04/11','danas@gmail.com','dana1234','http://www.google.co.il','',
'') <-- this
```

You need only 9 data because of the computed column.

Answer (score -1):

The number of values and data_types must be the same.

```
VALUES('1111','Dana','shwartz','1966/04/11','danas@gmail.com','dana1234','http://www.google.co.il','ds2016','sdd1','odd1')
```

10 values needed to pass. Now it must run.